# How to work with int values in gwt jsni methods

Tags: gwt

How is it possible to work with int values in jsni methods?

```java
public class Person extends JavaScriptObject{                                                                                                                     

   // some other methods

   public final native void setPoints(int i)/*-{
       this.points= this.points + i;
   }-*/;

   public final native int getPoints()/*-{
        return this.points;
   }-*/;                                                                                    
}
```

I am using this in a method combined with a JsArray

```
public static boolean moreThanZeroPoints(JsArray<Person> arr, int index){
     if(arr.get(index).getPoints() > 0){
         return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

In `arr.get(index).getPoints()` gives the following error-message:

```
    uncaught: Exception caught: Exception: caught: something other than an int was returned from JSNI method.
    package-path:: getPoints(): JS value of type undefined, expected int
```

For `arr.get(index).setPoints(1)` i get the same error-message.
What is wrong?
Please help.

Comment: What's the class that contains these methods? (a `JavaScriptObject` subclass I suppose?) What does "doesn't work" mean? (i.e. what does the code that calls these methods look like? what's the expected result? what's the actual result?)

Comment: Please add some code of this class. Seeing only this snippet it is very difficult to help you.

Comment: i edited my question. hope it helps.

Comment: As far as I see, you have `arr.get(index)`... without checking if `arr` has value on that index which leads possibly to some kind of OutOfBoundsException. I corrected your `setPoints` method's returning type to `void` because I thought it was just an  
erratum. If you have copied it right from your code then please revise that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `points` might not exist, you have to coerce `undefined` into some integer value in `getPoints()`; either that or add an `hasPoints()` method and only call `getPoints()` when `points` is defined.

```java
// coerce undefined (or null, or 0) to 0
public final native int getPoints() /*-{
  return this.points || 0;
}-*/;
```

or

```java
// coerce undefined or null to -1
public final native int getPoints() /*-{
  return (this.points != null) ? this.points : -1;
}-*/;
```

For `setPoints()`, you had declared a return type of `int` but never actually `return`ed anything, which is equivalent to returning `undefined` in JS. qben edited your answer and fixed it by changing the return type to `void`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the code did not reference the `JavaScript window object directly inside the method`. When accessing the browser's `window and document objects from JSNI`, you must reference them as `$wnd and $doc`, respectively. Your compiled script runs in a nested frame, and $wnd and $doc are automatically initialized to correctly refer to the `host page's window and document.`

```java
public final native int setPoints(int i)/-{ 
    $wnd.points=  $wnd.points + i;
 }-/;
```

And should like below:

```java
public final native int getPoints()/*-{
    return  eval('$wnd.' + points);;

}-*/;
```

Comment: @Baadshah, in this case Pero is using GWT Overlay Types which allow usage of `this` keyword in native methods which refers to underlying JS object. See [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay) for more details.